# Adding section / rows with an upwards animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

When adding items to my datasource I use `tableView.reloadData()` and adjusting the contentOffset of the table so the content stays at the same position with the new added section on top (not necessarily visible).

The code I use to do this looks like this:

```
// add item to data source

let height = tableView.contentSize.height
var offset = tableView.contentOffset

tableView.reloadData()

let newSet = CGPoint(x: offset.x, y: offset.y + tableView.contentSize.height - height)

tableView.contentOffset = newSet.y < 0 ? offset : newSet
```

This works, but there is no animation. What I'm trying to achieve is to add the section on top of the current section. If the new section is visible, it should move upwards.

If I insert the section instead of using `reloadData()`, then all the content below the new section will be animating downwards.

```
tableView.insertSections(IndexSet([1]), with: .automatic)
// All the content will move downwards even after setting the offset
```

What should I do to animate the new section upwards after inserting it to the table?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find a easy way. Maybe you can try:
1. Take screen shot before insert position
2. Cover the part before insert position
3. Change frame of your tableView to make sure the part below insert position don't move after reload
4. reload tableView
5. animate your screenshot to move up to reveal the new part